# Deprecated AnimatedList

Tags: flutter

I am learning how to make an `AnimatedList`. I ran the [example from the documentation](https://flutter.io/docs/catalog/samples/animated-list). Although it is not nearly as easy to understand and use as a `ListView`, the example worked. However, there was a message on the documentation page:

> This page is deprecated and its content may be out of date.

Usually when something is deprecated there is a better way to do it, but I cannot find any other information. What is wrong with that documentation page that makes it deprecated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this style of documentation has been discontinued.
Thus, the code is not up to date and also not maintained anymore.

[/docs/catalog/samples](https://flutter.io/docs/catalog/samples) is not really part of the *"Docs"* tab on **[flutter.io](https://flutter.io)** anymore.
It only redirects to a "curated list of samples", which is not related to the `/docs/catalog/samples/...` section of [flutter.io](https://flutter.io).

The `AnimatedList` class [can be found in the widgets documentation](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/AnimatedList-class.html).

Some of the widgets have samples built into their docs page. An example of this would be [`Column`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Column-class.html).
Hence, the conclusion that the old samples are not needed anymore.